# is IP2Location thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, thread-safety

I am currently looking to use IP2Location within an apache service. One thing I have noticed is that there is little information regarding whether or not IP2Location is thread safe.

```
IP2Location *IP2LocationObj = IP2Location_open("../data/IP-COUNTRY.BIN");
```

would the below be able to handle being used within multiple threads?

```
IP2LocationRecord *record = IP2Location_get_all(IP2LocationObj, "161.11.12.13");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this for a long time, as I can say it is thread safe.